# com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist file on Mac OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, dns, osx-yosemite

Can anyone who upgrades Mac OSX to Yosemite paste the result of the command?

```
sudo cat /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cat: /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist: No such file or directory

Comment: the same for me. as I see after some research this daemon were replaced by `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist`

Comment: Thanks! I can fix DNS problem by removing the file above I copied from OSX mavericks.